# Limit amount of posts made within a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-type

Is there a way to limit the number of posts that can be created within a custom taxonomy?

I have a custom post type called Preferred Agents and a custom taxonomy called Agent Location. I want to be able to limit the amount of Preferred Agents in an Agent Location to only 3. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I think you can approach it different way.. apply this restriction in the widget or template you are using to display the preferred agent's in that templates custom query limit posts to 3 ,  natively supported by wp wp query

Comment: Or in your theme or plugin one line of filter can be added get pre posts hook to set total posts to 3 whenever query for custom taxonomy preferred agent's is fetched from database.. see this post using similar approach https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198283/limiting-number-of-custom-posts-shown-on-taxonomy-page